# How to specify Kotlin version?

Tags: kotlin

I want to compile my Kotlin program using Kotlin `1.0.4`. What are the correct command line options for this purpose? I heard about `-version` option, but don't understand how to use it. `-version 1.0.4` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line argument for this purpose is `-language-version` and its value should be a major.minor Kotlin release version, of which there are only two at the moment: 1.0 and 1.1.

```
kotlinc -language-version 1.0 source.kt
```

To make analysis in IntelliJ IDEA be aware of the version the source will be compiled against, you can create a facet (Project Settings -> Facets -> "+") and select the language version in the dropdown there.